# Encoding json in utf-8 and upload to Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python script that export a json file to Amazon S3. It works but the problem is that I don't know how to use 'UTF-8'.

My code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
...
obj = s3.Object('ccvdb', 'file.json')
obj.put(Body=json.dumps(data),
    ContentType='charset=utf-8')
```

Output:

```
{"objectID": 10202, "type": "Coup\u00e9", "cars_getroute": "alfa-romeo-giulia-sprint-gt-veloce-bertone-coupe-1965-1967"}...
```

How to use utf-8 encoding in S3 with boto3 ?

EDIT: I found out the solution and replace the last line by `obj.put(Body=json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))`

Answer (score 1):

According to the boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put), this shouldn't even work. At least not in Python3+. The `put()` call requires `Body=` to be of type `bytes`, while `json.dumps()` [outputs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.dumps) a `str`. (Python2 wasn't so strict about `bytes` vs `str`)

UTF-8 is a way to convert a `str` (a series of characters) to `bytes`. You can simply call `whatever_string.encode('utf-8')` to do that conversion for you. In your code, simply add a `.encode('utf-c')` after your `json.dumps()` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work with `encode('utf-8')` alone. But it is with `obj.put(Body=json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))`